# How to download Expression Engine version 3 and 4?

Tags: ee2, ee3, php, ee

Please guide me how to download Expression Engine version 3 and 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two ways to get copies of EE 3 and 4.

`1)`
Log in to https://expressionengine.com. If you have any EE purchases from this site before, you can go to your Purchases page and download the latest 2, 3, and 4 versions of EE.

`2)`
Clone the git repository at https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/. There is a `master-v3` and `master-v4` branch you can fetch and switch to.